# Fastest way to assign values in data frame to matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame with Timestamp, StationId and Value as column names.

I would like to create a new matrix where the rows are Timestamps, columns are StationIds and the matrix elements are Values.

I have tried doing so using a loop but it is taking very long:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(res)) 
{
rmatrix[toString(res[row,"Timestamp"]),toString(res[row,"StationId"])] <- 
res[row,"Value"]
}
```

[The 'res' data frame looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QABvx.png) The timestamps are for a year, at 5mins interval. There are 62 unique station ids. The elements in the Value column are actually rainfall values.

[The rmatrix I'm trying to rearrange the data into looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRDhR.png) Each row is a unique timestamp at 5mins interval. Each column is the id of a station. The elements of the matrix are supposed to be the rainfall value for that station at that time.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Can send us the result of `dput(res)`?

Comment: Hi, have you tried gather regardless spread from tidyr? 
Or reshape can be an option, too.

Comment: @patL I don't see how that would be helpful. I have since added more information

Comment: @user1087590 I have tried, but don't see how it would be helpful.

Comment: @jsong005 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) thread in how to post a good reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- res %>% spread(StationIds,Values)
```